# Pass model to PartialAsync view (Razor, MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, razor, viewbag

I have **AccountController.cs** with below action:

```
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult Register()
 {
   ViewBag.Registration = GetRegistration();
   return View();
 }
```

**ViewBag.Registration** contains 2 elements and it's ok.

Then I got **Registration.cshtml** view:

```
@model Registration <!-- this model I'm using for other form -->   
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}    
<!-- some code -->

@await Html.PartialAsync("AllRegistered")
```

and **AllRegistered.cshtml** where data from **ViewBag.Registration** should be displayed:

```
@model IEnumerable<Registration>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Email)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.City)</th>
    </tr>

    @if (Model != null && Model.Count() != 0)
    {
        @foreach (Registration registration in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <th>@Html.DisplayFor(m => registration.Email)</th>
                <th>@Html.DisplayFor(m => registration.City)</th>
            </tr>
        }
     }
</table>
```

But nothing is generated into view, Model I think is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PartialAsync method contains an overload which includes the model:

`Html.PartialAsync(string partialViewName, TModel model)`

You should include the `IEnumerable<Registration>` (the partial view's model) in that helper.

If GetRegistrations() is returning that IEnumerable, you would define the partial view like this:

`@await Html.PartialAsync("AllRegistered", (List<Registration>)ViewBag.Registration)`

Comment: This is correct, but why use the ViewBag? This should also work:
@await Html.PartialAsync("AllRegistered", GetRegistration())
If you need multiple calls to GetRegistration(), you can also save it in a variable on the page.

Answer (score 1):

While Nathan's answer is perfectly correct, it would be more appropriate for this to be a view component. The fact that you want to display all registrations is a view detail that has nothing to do with the purpose of this action. As such, having the action be responsible for retrieving data requires it to have knowledge it doesn't need and shouldn't have.

Instead, add a class like:

```
public class AllRegistrationsViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    private readonly RegistrationsService _service;

    public AllRegistrationsViewComponent(RegistrationService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
    {
        // logic behind `GetRegistrations()` here
        return View(registrations);
    }
}
```

The reference here to `RegistrationsService` is just whatever means you're using to retrieve your registrations, to show how to inject that into the component. This might be your context or something else entirely.

Then, create the view `Views/Components/AllRegistrations/Default.cshtml` with:

```
@model IEnumerable<Registration>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Email)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.City)</th>
    </tr>

    @if (Model != null && Model.Count() != 0)
    {
        @foreach (Registration registration in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <th>@Html.DisplayFor(m => registration.Email)</th>
                <th>@Html.DisplayFor(m => registration.City)</th>
            </tr>
        }
     }
</table>
```

The `AllRegistrations` part of the path is based on the name of the view component, without the `ViewComponent` part, so if you name it differently, adjust here as well.

Finally, in your view:

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("AllRegistrations")
```

Then, your action can just focus on its actual purpose:

```
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult Register()
{
    return View();
}
```